# Special Elements: Spectrum

Tags: functional-analysis, spectral-theory, c-star-algebras

Given a C*-algebra with unit $1\in\mathcal{A}$.

For normal elements one has:
$$A^*=A^{-1}\iff\sigma(A)\subseteq\mathbb{S}$$
$$A^*=A\iff\sigma(A)\subseteq\mathbb{R}$$
$$A\geq0\iff\sigma(A)\subseteq\mathbb{R}^+$$
$$A^2=A=A^*\iff\sigma(A)\subseteq\{0,1\}$$

For nonnormal elements this characterization breaks:
$$N:=\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\0&0\end{pmatrix}:\quad\sigma(N)=\{0\}$$
But I'm still missing an example for a nonunitary element:
$$\sigma(N)\subseteq\mathbb{S}:\quad N^*\neq N^{-1}$$
Do you have one at hand, please?

Comment: By the way, your first equivalence is false, assuming $\mathbb{B} = \{ z \in \mathbb{C} : |z| \leq 1\}$. For example, the zero operator has spectrum in $\mathbb{B}$ but $0^*0 \neq 1$. In fact, for normal elements $A^*A=1$ implies $A$ is unitary. Regarding your fifth equivalence, it may interest you to know that, for normal elements, $A^2 = A$ already implies that $A^*=A$.

Comment: Ah right $AA^*=A^*A=1$ but $A^*=(A^2)^*=(A^*)^2=\ldots$?

Comment: It's a consequence of spectral theory. Basically, if $f$ is a complex-valued function and $f\cdot f = f$ then every value of $f$ is a number $z \in \mathbb{C}$ such that $z^2=z$. The only such numbers are $0$ and $1$, so $\mathrm{range}(f) \subset \{0,1\}$.

Comment: Ah ok, so I will delete the first one but keep the last one the way it is right now just for clarity; but good point. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already found a non-normal operator $N$ with spectrum $\{0\}$. Now simply note that
$1+N$ will be another non-normal operator with spectrum $\{1\}$.